# Best ways to max town halls

Tags: clash-of-clans

I would like to fully upgrade my town halls to max as fast as possible so what would be the fastest way to do that?

Comment: Spend a lot of money on gems. Instant resources and instant build times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ellesedil said, you can spend a lot of gems to upgrade faster. If you don't want to use gems, you should always keep your builders busy. Attack as much as you can and collect a lot of resources for your upgrades so that as soon as a builders gets free you have resources to start the next upgrade.

Also it is important you get all builders asap. If you don't buy gems, try your best not to use gems for upgrades and boosts and save them for builders. The more buidlers you have the more upgrades you can do simultaneously. You can use gems after you get all 5 builders in such case.

Another point is to delay the upgrades of elixir collectors and gold mines until th8-9. As you get a lot of resources from attacks, you won't need to depend on your own collectors and mines. Also th8 onwards you will have so many troops to upgrade but comparatively less buildings to build and upgrade, so you will have builders free. That would be the best time to upgrade the collectors and mines.